# XPath only get nodes from table when another node exists

Tags: xpath

I have a specific problem concerning XPath.

Say I can get a column from the table using this query:
    `//div[@id="someid"]/table/tbody/tr/td[9]/text()`

However, I want to only get this column when another specific node exists.

I tried using:
    `//div[@id="someid"]/table/tbody/tr/td[9 and boolean(//a/span[@title='specifictitle'])]`

This however does not work as it returns all items in the table.

I have a few specific limitations:
- `//div[@id="someid"]/table/tbody/tr` is static and cannot be changed. 
- The `td` contains no other info concerning what column it is in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 approaches:

## First - as a direct condition within square brackets:

```
//div[@id="someid"]/table/tbody/tr[//a/span[@title='specifictitle']]/td[9]/text()
```

this approach is simpler and the position does not matter

this is also the approach that fulfills the OPs requirement, that the query should start with `//div[@id="someid"]/table/tbody/tr`

* You can basically put the condition `[//a/span[@title='specifictitle']]` to whatever element in the query you want (could also be behind tbody or table etc.)

## Second - using axes (for example ancestor)

2 cases regarding the position of your element within HTML code:

1) anchor-element "before" your div with "someid":

```
//a/span[@title='specifictitle']//div[@id="someid"]/table/tbody/tr/td[9]/text()
```

2) anchor-element "after" your div with "someid":

```
//a/span[@title='specifictitle']/ancestor::div[@id="someid"]/table/tbody/tr/td[9]/text()
```

In both cases the xpath-query will not return a result if the `//a/span[@title='specifictitle']` does not exist, which is what you needed, if I understood correctly